# Android Webview Disable Form input Zoom

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I've been having issues trying to get webview from stop zooming in when a user clicks a input field on webview.  How can I keep webview from stop zooming in?

Heres my code:

```
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom (true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

    String form = "<form action='demo_form.asp'><input type='text' name='email' style='font-size: 200%;width:78%;float:left'><input type='submit' value='Submit' style='float:right;width:20%;font-size: 200%'></form>";
    String summary = "<html><body>"+form+"</body></html>";


    wv.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: I added this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">  It doesnt zoom in anymore but changed all my image sizes